# Complex integration along a circle not centered at the origin

Tags: complex-integration, line-integrals

I need to evaluate $∮_C\overline{z}^2dz$ around |$z-1|=1$.  I understand that this is a circle with radius $1$ centered at $(1,0)$.  I know how to do this if the circle is centered at the origin.  $\overline{z}^2=e^{-2i\theta}$ and $dz=-2ie^{-2i\theta}$.
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-2i\theta}\left(-2ie^{-2i\theta}\right)d\theta=-2i\left[\frac{e^{-4i\theta}}{-3i}\right]_0^{2\pi}=-2i\left(\frac{1}{-3i}-\frac{1}{-3i}\right)=0$$
So now, how can I modify this to account for the circle shifting?

Comment: @gt6989b : Doesn't Cauchy require holomorphic integrand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The parametric equation of a circle centered at $z_0$ is just $z(t) = z_0 + re^{it}$ (where $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$).

Comment: So $z_0$ and $r$ are $1$.  Then $\overline{z}(t)=1+e^{-it}$, $\overline{z}^2(t)=1+e^{-2it}+2e^{-it}$, and $dz=-ie^{-it}dt$?

Comment: Hmm, since $z=1+e^{it}$, I think $dz = ie^{it}\;dt$, right? It isn't $d\bar{z}$ after all...